# Google Cloud Endpoints stability?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using this [link](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae) to build a simple chat application using GCM, and I found this great feature "Google Cloud Endpoints" which makes things easier. But I am afraid to depend on it as I noticed it is still experimental. Can I trust it or should I use Java Servlets instead?

Answer (score 3):

It is true that the tag 'experimental' is a bit scary.  If you are concerned, you could consider holding back a bit until Google IO 2013, which is the middle of May.  They often make announcement and introduce new technologies there.

They first announced endpoints at last years' Google IO (in July) and if there any significant changes pending for endoints they would likely announce them at this years'.

If you do start using Endpoints, just for Android, and w/o user authentication, I don't think it would be too hard to revert to using a Servlet instead, if you had to (i.e. due to a change in terms that was off-putting).  The user authentication stuff would be harder to replace IMO.

Comment: As we [announced](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2013/02/java-7-and-cloud-endpoints-preview.html) in February, Cloud Endpoints is not _Experimental_, it is in _Preview_, meaning we are behind it.

Comment: Duly noted @Tom, thanks for the feedback. I think it's definitely valuable for those coming up with these terms and I'll pass along.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have used Google Cloud Endpoints they work perfectly. Furthermore many interesting features are already implemented, such as integration with [Google Eclipse Plugin](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-overview) and testing through the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/), even in localhost, using the [Development Server](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver).

I understand they're still experimental maybe because they're just a new technology not really thoroughly tested yet and are subject to updates. Anyway I've not found significant bugs so far and you should be able to reuse your endpoints with the sucesive versions that will exist. It doesn't seem to be something that will dissapear in the near future...

Comment: It is good to hear that they work perfectly with you,So let's try.
Thank you @Miko :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but for further references I want to say that my short experience was not so pleasant.

I tried "Mobile Backend App". In the beginning, everything worked fine, but after a few days (without changing anything) I received:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException 404 Not Found
```

I sow other posts on stackoverflow and manage to solve it by creating another project. I changed the code and it still worked. But again I had problems I played a bit with the 2 projects, I redeployed and changed the settings (tips found on other posts) and it worked. Now it is no longer working, no matter what I do.

I hope that the problem is specific to this project, but nevertheless it is frustrating.